# Space between two words and link issue

Tags: php, html, mysql

First of all, i want to say that i searched a solution for this problem but i couldn't find.

The problem is ; in my database i have more than 2000 rows and some of them has two words and after fetching this data from db i'm using this words as a link. For example ;

```
<a href=/'.$row['word'].'.html >'.$row['word'].'</a>
db word = one
```

This code works with one word perfectly and result is : *site.com/one.html*

but if i have a value in db like "one two" and if i use this code again

```
<a href=/'.$row['word'].'.html >'.$row['word'].'</a>
db word = one two
```

then the result is: *site.com/one*

but actually it should be : *site.com/one+two.html* or at least, it must add the second word.

on the page i see the "one two" words but when i click on it, it goes to *site.com/one*

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be urlencoding the strings

```
'<a href="/' . urlencode($row['word']) . '.html" >' . $row['word'] . '</a>'
```

Comment: Thank you @adeneo, you are right. i changed the code as you said and it worked. thank you again. I'll mark your answer as the correct answer but i must wait 8 mins.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a custom character as word divider

```
$url = implode('-',explode(" ",$row['word']));
'<a href="/' . urlencode($url) . '.html" >' . $row['word'] . '</a>'
```

Comment: thank you. it will also help for determinate a specific character between two words.